# Some key string (like "%something") make PyYAML parser crash

Tags: python, pyyaml

I'm trying to parse YAML translations file using PyYAML, but some keys make it crash:

```
import yaml
t = yaml.load("%users users have connected: %users users have connected")
```

The error is `"expected alphabetic or numeric character, but found ' '"`

Comment: the error seems pretty clear, how does the data you're feeding to the scanner look like?

Comment: This translation file is not from a Python application, it's working. The error raised by the parser is pretty clean but I can't change the files I'm supposed to process.

Answer (score 0):

Search for '%u' on the [Python built-in types documentation.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

%u is an obsolete string interpolation code that's the same as %d. Python thinks you're trying to interpolate a string. It should parse properly if you were to change it to:

```
t = yaml.load("%users users have connected: %users users have connected" % users)
```

It still wouldn't give you what you're probably expecting, though, as the resulting string would be:

```
10sers users have connected: 10sers users have connected
```

You can escape the '%' character, or wrap the translation key in curly brackets and use string formatting, like this:

```
d = {"users": 10}
t = yaml.load("\{users\} users have connected: \{users\} users have connected")

print t.replace('\\','').format(**d)
>>> '10 users'
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can get it into a string without complaint by escaping the '%'s using:

```
t = yaml.load(s.replace('%', '\%')).replace('\%', '%')
```

Where 's' is the string from the translation file.

Comment: You're offering me to change my problem not to solve it. The provided code was a minimal reproduction of the problem, I'm loading some translation files that are not from a Python environment.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear on what the actual problem was. It's still the fact that it's trying to interpolate %u and format the string. The only way I've found to get that string into a variable without it complaining is: t = yaml.load(s.replace('%', '\%')).replace('\%', '%') where 's' is the string from the translation.

Comment: I've finally quoted my keys in my input file but your comment seems good, could you update your answer according to that ?

Comment: @AsTeR: Done. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the same error, PyYAML 3.11 and Python2.7.10 give:

```
yaml.parser.ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found '<stream end>'
  in "<string>", line 1, column 57:
     ... ted: %users users have connected
```

but you are starting the line here with a `%` and that should be followed by a directive. There are currently only two directives defined are `YAML` and `TAG` and all other strings are [reserved for future use](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2781147).

The YAML spec also [states](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2800967):

> A bare document does not begin with any directives or marker lines. Such documents are very “clean” as they contain nothing other than the content. In this case, the first non-comment line may not start with a “%” first character.

That effectively means that the string `%users users have connected: %users users have connected` is incorrect YAML, and that, if this is a scalar, you have to put it in quotes. The following however I expected to be correct YAML:

```
- %users users have connected: %users users have connected
```

but PyYAML doesn't accept it and you have to use quotes here as well.